# How to get column in error within InvalidRowException event handler?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have a winform with Devexpress GridView.

I'm handling the event : **InvalidRowException**

When data is missing in mandatory columns (or data is not consistent in general), I'm trying to show a customized message.

The problem is that I can't find a way to the get the column that has the error.

In the object **E as InvalidRowExceptionEventArgs**, there is no information about the column. I tried also : **gridview.getcolumnerror(gridview.columns(1))** but it returns nothing.

Can anyone know how to get a column with error when handling the event **InvalidRowException** please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InvalidRowException` does give you the row both with `Row` and `RowHandle` properties.  Here you can investigate and handle what exactly is wrong on a per-row basis.

To answer your question about "which column has the error" please look at the `InvalidRowExceptionArgs.Exception` property.  This should make it clear exactly why it considers it an "invalid row".

Documentation about this with examples can be found [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.InvalidRowException.event).

If you can post complete, small and reproducible code along with what behavior you intend to achieve I might be to to write the code to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

Catching that exception is a bit too late, so you cannot handle anything in the grid. Use the event `ValidateRow` to prevent unsufficient data entries. Both are explained in [this article](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.InvalidRowException.event).

There are other approaches as well like validating directly when a cell editor was left (and not just when the row is left). See [this tutorial on Data Input and Validation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114741/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Getting-Started/Walkthroughs/Data-Editing/Tutorial-Data-Input-Validation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually "Missing Data" is just an example.I do handle missing data. The question is related to any inconsistency in data in general. For example duplicate values in columns with unique constraint or other reasons. Is there any way to get the column that raised an exception ?

Comment: I meant you should change from handling the exception to input validation. For example, the event `ValidatingEditor` gives you the row and the column (and the value to validate) *before* the grid throws the exception.  https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView.ValidatingEditor.event

Comment: Sometimes it's not possible. For example, Duplicate columns with unique constraint. Should I browse all the rows manually to check if the key is not duplicated ? That's not possible...